# SWIG interface file for c++ header files

Tags: swig

I have c++ a.h file like this

```
class myClass
{
private: 
  int a;
public: 
  myClass(){} 
  void foo(){}
};
```

How must look like SWIG interface file? 
Is this true?

```
%module a
%{
#include "a.h"
%}
```

Answer (score 5):

No, `%{ ... %}` adds the included code directly to the generated SWIG wrapper.  To process the header for interfaces to expose, `%include` needs to be used.

```
%module a
%{                // This adds the include to the generated wrapper.
#include "a.h"
%}
%include "a.h"    // This *processes* the include and makes wrappers.
```

If you have direct code not in a header needs to be added to the wrapper AND processed for interfaces, then `%inline` can be used to avoid duplication:

```
%module a
%inline %{
class myClass
{
private: 
  int a;
public: 
  myClass(){} 
  void foo(){}
};
%}
```

Comment: Is it possible to work with multiple header files? I was hoping to have just one `.i` file that includes all required header files and exports/generates the files interfaces.

Comment: @Mark: The second example doesn't work when the Python is used as a target. Checked for SWIG-4.0 and Python-3.7.9

Comment: @EvgenyP.Kurbatov If it doesn’t work for you, something else is wrong. This is right out of the Swig documentation and I’ve used the technique with Python.  Post a question with a reproducible example.

Comment: @Mark, I did. Please take a look, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68700101/swig-python-and-interface-file-with-inline-directive

Comment: @EvgenyP.Kurbatov Thanks, when I'ved used `%inline` in the past I relalized I've always used it with inline code like the edit I made above.  Since `%inline` both includes and processes the file, it works like the first example except uses `#include` in both cases and `#include` doesn't generate SWIG interfaces on the processing path.