# SWIG, Python and interface file with inline directive

Tags: python, c, swig

I have Ubuntu-20.04, Anaconda-3 (installed into the user dir) with Python-3.7.9 and SWIG-4.0.

Here are my files.

`a.h`:

```c
void foo(void);
```

`a.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"
void foo(void) { printf("Foo!\n"); }
```

`a.i`:

```
%module a
%inline %{
#include "a.h"
%}
```

`test.py`:

```python
import a
a.foo()
```

Compile script `compile.sh`:

```sh
A=$HOME/opt/anaconda3
I=$A/include/python3.7m
gcc -c -fpic -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I$I a.c
$A/bin/swig -python -py3 a.i
gcc -c -fpic -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I$I a_wrap.c
gcc -shared a.o a_wrap.o -o _a.so
```

After compilation the test script produces

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    a.foo()
AttributeError: module 'a' has no attribute 'foo'
```

However, if I write a longer interface file everything is OK:

```
%module a
%{
#include "a.h"
%}
%include "a.h"
```

**UPD** @Jens suggested to replace `#` with `%` in the first (short) interface file. In this case I got

```
a_wrap.c:2701:1: error: expected identifier or '(' before '%' token
 2701 | %include "a.h"
      | ^
a_wrap.c:2720:12: error: '_wrap_foo' undeclared here (not in a function)
 2720 |   { "foo", _wrap_foo, METH_NOARGS, NULL},
      |            ^~~~~~~~~
gcc: error: a_wrap.o: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It would make sense to describe in your post how in the first run you are invoking swig and which steps you are taking to compile the example. As you state that everything works fine for the longer interface file, the cause can probably be found there.

Comment: You need the `%include` for SWIG to know of foo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%inline` both includes the braced code directly in the SWIG-generated wrapper code, but also processes it to generated target language interfaces.  So this:

```c
%module a
%inline %{
void foo(void);
%}
```

is equivalent to:

```c
%module a
%{
void foo(void) {}
%}
void foo(void) {}
```

But this:

```c
%module a
%inline %{
#include "a.h"
%}
```

is equivalent to:

```c
%module a
%{
#include "a.h"
%}
#include "a.h"  // NOT the same as %include "a.h" and isn't processed for interfaces
```

To show that `%inline` is both included and processed, I made:

```c
%module a
%inline %{
#include "a.h"   // ignored in "include-in-wrapper" pass
#ifdef SWIG
%include "a.h"   // processed in "wrap-with-SWIG" pass
#endif
%}
```

The above did the right thing and exposed the interface, but it's worse than just using:

```c
%module a
%{
#include "a.h"
%}
%include "a.h"
```

`%inline` is really for inserting new functions into the wrapper and exposing the interface, such as this:

```c
%module a
%inline %{
class myClass
{
private: 
  int a;
public: 
  myClass(){} 
  void foo(){}
};
%}
```

where otherwise you'd have to write, at a minimum:

```c
%module a

%{ // new functionality added to wrapper
class myClass
{
private: 
  int a;
public: 
  myClass(){} 
  void foo(){}
};
%}

class myClass   // process the interface
{
public:         // note don't need to repeat private part or
  myClass();    // implementation, just public declarations to be exposed.
  void foo();
};
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mark, it's clean now. Don't understand why SWIG is not using the `#` prefix in both cases, especially since all of this is about C/C++.

Comment: @EvgenyP.Kurbatov SWIG processing directives start with `%` and are not C/C++ even if some are look like it.